# PyQt: Adding multiple widgets to layout

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I'm trying to setup a graphics view using Pyqt. I have a vertical box layout in which I want to add a GLViewWidget object and then a GraphicsLayoutWidget. But when I add these widgets to the vertical box layout, the GraphicsLayoutWidget takes over the whole layout where I cannot see the GLViewWidget object. I've included the code below.

```
class view_manager(QtCore.QObject):
       def __init__(self):
            super(view_manager, self).__init__()
            self._layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

            self._detectorView = viewport()
            self._layout.addWidget(self._detectorView)

            b = QtGui.QPushButton("HEY")
            self._layout.addWidget(b)

            self._plotView = self.getPlot()
            self._layout.addWidget(self._plotView)

    def getLayout(self):
            return self._layout

    def getPlot(self):
            plot_widget = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()

            #plot_widget.resize(800,350)
            plt1 = plot_widget.addPlot()
            plt2 = plot_widget.addPlot()

            ## make interesting distribution of values
            vals = numpy.hstack([numpy.random.normal(size=500), numpy.random.normal(size=260, loc=4)])

            ## compute standard histogram
            y,x = numpy.histogram(vals, bins=numpy.linspace(-3, 8, 40))

            ## Using stepMode=True causes the plot to draw two lines for each sample.
            ## notice that len(x) == len(y)+1
            plt1.plot(x, y, stepMode=True, fillLevel=0, brush=(0,0,255,150))

            ## Now draw all points as a nicely-spaced scatter plot
            y = pg.pseudoScatter(vals, spacing=0.15)
            #plt2.plot(vals, y, pen=None, symbol='o', symbolSize=5)
            plt2.plot(vals, y, pen=None, symbol='o', symbolSize=5, symbolPen=(255,255,255,200), symbolBrush=(0,0,255,150))

            plot_widget.show()
            return plot_widget
```

The detectorView object inherits from GLViewWidget. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: After extensive searching, I found the solution. Calling  setSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding) from my GLViewWidget fixes the issue.

Comment: instead of comment you must write a solution and mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive searching, I found the solution. Calling `setSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)`
from my GLViewWidget fixed this issue.

Comment: another option may include setting the minimum or maximum height for your widgets.... i.e. `self._detectorView.setMinimumHeight(HEIGHT)`